# Chrome keeps adding these default search engines even though I keep deleting them

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have scanned with Malwarebytes, and also used the cleanup feature within Chrome to check for malicious extensions but could not find anything.
What else can I do to ensure Chrome does not add back whichever search engines I have deleted?

The additional search engines are shown as per screenshot:

[image: Yahoo]

[image: Search settings]

Comment: None of those search engines are hostile or malicious.

Comment: They will by added by Google for 2 reasons, first, they may get paid to list them, and second, the authorities may require them to list others due to anti monopoly requirements.

Answer (score 1):

From [Edge Talk](https://edgetalk.net/stop-remove-custom-search-engine-chrome/): "When you search on a website for a few times in Chrome, Chrome will add it as a custom search engine, aka OpenSearch, along with special keyboard shortcut for you to use it."

*Edge Talk* site also suggest the add-on, [Don't add custom search engines](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-add-custom-search-en/dnodlcololidkjgbpeoleabmkocdhacc). As with any add-on, check reviews and note to what it has access before adding.

That said, when Chrome updates, it likely will install more search engines -- inclusion in Chrome is a revenue stream. The easiest thing, then, is to just [**deactivate** unwanted engines](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop), and ignore them, since they are visible *only* in the list at *Manage search engines and site search*.

Answer (score 0):

The default search engine is the one you set. Those are just additionals you can choose from. It's not malware either, it's Google being user-friendly...

There's an extension for that, named **[Don't add custom search engines](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-add-custom-search-en/dnodlcololidkjgbpeoleabmkocdhacc?hl=en)**.

Comment: I have to delete them regularly because it interferes with my own script of adding custom search engines (not the ones auto-added by Chrome/other websites). Is there a way to stop ONLY those search engines I listed above from being added every time Chrome is updated?

Comment: Well then that ext obviously would hamper as well... you might need to write your own. This extension answers your initial question. I think the best way forward would be now to accept one of the answers here and ask a new question, either here or in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Something like "I use this script `script you wrote` to add custom search engines but Chrome automatically keeps adding these engines ... which interferes with my script, how can prevent the interference".

Comment: @Automator_Junkie, If you script adding extensions, then script *removing* (or *disabling*) those unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: McAfee Web Advisor adds Yahoo! search and Secure Search as defaults without asking permission - if you install or reinstall McAfee Web Advisor, they will reappear, and you have to go into the Chrome Settings to delete them. Very annoying.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).